# How to avoid the frame layout is pushed up when the soft keyboard appears?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-framelayout

I am facing the issue ,when the soft keyboard is appeared the frame layout in top of the activity is pushed up .The Frame  Layout is placed inside the Linear Layout and below the scrollview is placed inside the scrollview multiple edittext are placed . I have tried the answers posted in the stack overflow but still my problem is not solved.
I am buliding the app in target sdk version 25 and mimimum version 16.

I applied `below method to the activity in AndroidManifestFile.

```
 <activity android:name=".Activities.ScamLookUpActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>`
```

I don't know how to solve this error and tell the reason the why the given method is not appllied to my activity.

This is my xml layout file...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_scam_look_up"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#eee"
tools:context="com.zcodia.scamlookup.Activities.ScamLookUpActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@mipmap/bg_splash_cut">


    </View>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:background="#A82A37" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_buton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/menu"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>

    <com.zcodia.scamlookup.Utils.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scam lookup"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f9f9f9"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_input2"
   >

    <com.zcodia.scamlookup.Utils.CustomTextView
        android:text="Search Scam Database"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:typeface="sans"
        />

    <com.zcodia.scamlookup.Utils.CustomTextView
        android:text="Contact Medium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/details_id"
        android:textColor="#D32F2F"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>

<com.zcodia.scamlookup.Utils.CustomTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Category"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textColor="#D32F2F"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative_spinner"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textinput"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <Spinner

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/categorySpinner"
        android:text="@string/inheritance"
        android:prompt="@string/inheritance"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textinput"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <Spinner

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/categorySpinner2"
            android:text="@string/inheritance"
            android:prompt="@string/inheritance"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.zcodia.scamlookup.Utils.CustomEditText
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber_editText"
        android:hint="@string/phonenumber"
        android:typeface="sans"
        style="@style/CustomFontStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/yourLocation"
            android:hint="Location"
            android:textColorHint="#757575"
            style="@style/CustomFontStyle"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="330dp"
            android:text="&#xf041;"
            android:id="@+id/scammer_location_font"
            android:textColor="#3eb3a0"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.zcodia.scamlookup.Utils.CustomEditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/scammer_location"
        android:id="@+id/scammerLocation_editText"
        android:typeface="sans"
        style="@style/CustomFontStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     />

    <com.zcodia.scamlookup.Utils.CustomEditText

        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/keyWord"
        android:id="@+id/keyword_edittext"
        android:background="@drawable/textinput"
        android:typeface="sans"
        style="@style/CustomFontStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      />

</LinearLayout>

    <com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/clip_flow_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    </com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <com.zcodia.scamlookup.Utils.CustomButton
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/search_id"
            android:background="@mipmap/bg_splash_cut"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

```
</ScrollView>
```

The below image is my activity.

[image]

when the edittext is pressed the top frame layout is pushed up.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try "statehidden" and "adjustPan" together.

`<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">`

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer,

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply this attribute to your Scroll view:`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and Follow this

[link](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec)

Comment: u can use Linear layout instead of Frame Layout.

Comment: can you put the image then i can suggest exactly what u want?

Comment: I didn't tried in linear layout , i tried only in frame layout

Comment: whole layout put in Scroll view and set attribute     android:fitsSystemWindows="true" and in manifest file add  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and put image so i can make  layout

Comment: when you pressed any edit text then what happened with your Frame layout?

Comment: my frame layout is pushed up and it is hidden ...when the soft key board is closed the frame layout is come down to visible position